# Trying to understand schematics

Tags: batteries, schematics, wiring, input

I'm making a guitar pedal project,  and I have a very basic understanding of electronics, so I'm having a hard time understanding some of the logic behind the schematic I have.

[image: Stereo jack input]

Why would I need to connect the battery to the jack input?

My original question was why would I need a stereo jack input if a guitar uses a mono jack, but looking at the schematic just made things worse for me.

Answer (score 1):

Plugging in a mono TS plug into the stereo TRS jack connects the battery to rest of circuit, and unplugging disconnects the battery. So the input plug couples as a power switch to save battery.

Comment: I see, so if I had an on/off switch I could use a TS plug instead right?